# Makefile error: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, makefile

I've got this directory structure:

- `.\src` contains all the source code (`.h` and `.cpp`)
- `.\bin` should have all the `.o` and `.bin`
- `.` has `Makefile`

This is my current Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -g
CC = g++
EXEC = flrfile
SRC_DIR = src
BIN_DIR = bin
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.cpp)
OBJ := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%,%,$(SOURCES))
OBJ := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(OBJ))
OBJ := $(addprefix ../$(BIN_DIR)/,$(OBJ))

all: flrfile

../$(BIN_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/%.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp -o $@

$(EXEC): $(OBJ)
    @mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(BIN_DIR)/$(OBJ) -o $(BIN_DIR)/$(EXEC)

.PHONY : clean

clean:
    -rm -rf $(BIN_DIR)
```

When I run `make` I get this error:

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic -g -c src/%.cpp -o ../bin/FixedLengthFieldsRecord.o
g++: error: src/%.cpp: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [../bin/FixedLengthFieldsRecord.o] Error 4
```

Why is this? I have little to no understanding of Makefile to be honest...

Comment: Related: Since your are using `g++`, you should be using `CXXFLAGS`. In addition, there's a whole new world for [C/C++/Objective C Toolchain Hardening](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/C-Based_Toolchain_Hardening). Many in the free software world are oblivious to it.

Comment: And instead of using $(CC) (and assigning it another value than its default), you can use $(CXX), whose default value is usually g++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct line for compiling should look like this:

```
$(BIN_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp $(SRC_DIR)/%.h
    $(CXX) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Which means: "for every file matching the pattern "%.o" in $(BIN_DIR), compile it using the associated $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp as argument (first dependency)

Additional comment: I suspect some missing dependencies: usually, a .c or cpp source file doesn't **only** depend on the corresponding header file, but might also include other headers from the project.

Comment: I edited my Makefile with your suggestion, and now get this error:  `make: *** No rule to make target '../bin/FixedLengthFieldsRecord.o', needed by 'flrfile'.  Stop.`

Comment: This does not come from the recipe I gave here, but from the 'link' recipe: you have the following dependency:`$(OBJ)`, which resolves to something like `../bin/FixedLengthFieldsRecord.o` so make searches a recipe to build that file, and it doesn't find any, hence the error message.

Comment: replacing `OBJ := $(addprefix ../$(BIN_DIR)/,$(OBJ))` by `OBJ := $(addprefix $(BIN_DIR)/,$(OBJ))` should make it.

Comment: now I get `Fatal error: can't create bin/FixedLengthFieldsRecord.o: No such file or directory` :(

Comment: Does the folder `bin` exist ?